# Selenium - Custom Firefox profile

Tags: selenium-rc

I've setup a new firefox profile for use with Selenium (accepted certificate warnings for local QA site).

But, I keep getting told the profile directory does not exist.

This is the line from my batch file

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate ~/"C:\Documents and Settings\dadams\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\k39jzisz.SeleniumUser"
```

but the message I get is:

```
Firefox profile template doesn't exist: C:\Installs\selenium-remote-control-1.0.
3\selenium-server-1.0.3\~\C:\Documents and Settings\dadams\Application Data\Mozi
lla\Firefox\Profiles\k39jzisz.SeleniumUser
```

Can anyone tell me what I have notdoen correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was actually the location of the profile.

I created a new profile and put it in "c:\lib\selenium\ff_profile"
as suggested on: http://agileqatesting.com/?p=27

and it seems to work correctly!

so the line in the batch file now looks like

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\lib\selenium\ff_profile"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you start your server is correct, just do not mention the user home directory (~/) then it should be fine. I am not sure if the backward slash () works, if not try out with forward slashes (/):

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\Documents and Settings\dadams\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\k39jzisz.SeleniumUser"
```