# Bad request issue with latest version of selenium and firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, headless-browser

I am working on phpunit-selenium for browser automation with headless Firefox. I updated both selenium and Firefox to latest version. And it started throwing error for me.

```
“PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Bad request“
```

Now I googled for this and found that this issue is related to hosts files:

[Unable to call FirefoxDriver constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214915/unable-to-call-firefoxdriver-constructor)

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3280

But I cannot update hosts file due to application restrictions. Is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the profile should resolve the issue for you.

Note that this is a Java code fragment, You would have to do something similar with the php API:

```
   profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE,"set.myhost.com");
```

Comment: Yeah I notice this in java. But not able to find any documentation/help in php for same.

Comment: I hope these answers help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328494/selenium2-firefox-use-the-default-profile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791156/how-does-one-use-a-custom-firefox-profile-with-phpunits-webdriver-framework

Comment: Here is the feature request to add firefox profile in php, Check your version. https://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/issues/detail?id=18

Comment: Not sure if this idea is feasible or not .. If i create separate host file and set Firefox to consider that file as host .:(